# Чем смотреть исполняемый код .net приложения?

Tags: .net, декомпиляция, поиск-программ, jit

Хочу полазить по скомпилированному приложению, чтобы увидеть оптимизации, производимые jit-компилятором.

Какие программы использовать, чтобы получить листинг нативного кода после прохода jit и их меппинг на инструкции il-кода? В идеале бы ещё меппинг на C#-код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запустите или присоединитесь к своему приложению отладчиком Visual Studio, установите брекпойнт в интересующем месте, и когда он сработает - выберите пункт меню "Debug/Windows/Disassembly".

Опции для показа IL там нет. Можно только установить галочку "Show source code", и тогда будет показан маппинг машинного и исходного кода(на C#, VB.NET, или на другом языке, на котором вы программируете).

Comment: Немного смущает фраза "в режиме отладки" - насколько мне известно, код в debug'е и release'е будет сильно отличаться. Хотя breakpoint же можно и в релизе поставить. PS: Сорри, студии сейчас под рукой нет, вечером обязательно попробую.

Comment: Тогда запустите приложение без отладчика, и приаттачьте отладчик к нему! В режиме «под отладчиком» и правда многие оптимизации отключаются.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, слегка двусмысленно написал изначально - с обычными, не отладочными сборками это естественно тоже работает. Переформулировал.

Comment: @VladD, а если запускается отдельное приложение студией в режиме отладки, то как для него проект с исходниками указать?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Если у вас приложение скомпилировано на этой машине, то рядом с exe лежат pdb, в которых прописаны правильные пути к исходникам. Так что по идее должно подхватить автоматически.

Comment: JIT в момент компиляции IL в машинный код проверяет на наличие отладчика, и отключает оптимизации (даже если код собран в Release!). Самый надежный метод - поставить вызов `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` прямо в том коде, который хочется посмотреть. И приаттачить отладчик после появления системного диалога. Обычные брекпойнты не всегда срабатывают (Unable to resolve breakpoint at...) т.к. при полной оптимизации методы/свойства часто инлайнятся/flow перестраивается и строчке в cs может не найтись точного соответствия в машинном коде.

Comment: Угу, надо, чтобы jitter _уже_ пробежал. Например, вызвать функцию дважды.