# C#. В чем разница между реализацией обобщенного класса через параметризацию типом и через тип object?

Tags: c#, generics, объекты, c#-faq

Меня интересует этот вопрос с точки зрения производительности. Про то что object требует приведение типов и из-за этого можно неявно допустить ошибку, я знаю.

UPD. Этот вопрос был задан на собеседовании. В качестве примера добавил 2 класса:

```
class SomeClass<T>
{
    private T[] storage;
}

class SomeClass
{
    private object[] storage;
}
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы привести пример реализации обобщенного класса через тип `object`? И сказать, чем это удобно и где применить? Раз уж такой вопрос, то думаю, стоит объяснить причину данного вопроса. Просто мне не совсем понятно, зачем реализовывать заведомо ошибочный подход, который приведет к проблемам, причем Вы сами об этом догадываетесь, как видно из вопроса.

Comment: Добавил пример. Этот вопрос мне задали на собеседовании.

Comment: я уж подумал, что Вы осознанно такое решили реализовать ))) для собеседования хороший вопрос)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

В том случае, если вы используете значимые типы, вы получаете дополнительные накладные расходы на [упаковку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435408) и последующую распаковку.

```
var numbers = new List<object>();
numbers.Add(1); // упаковка №1
numbers.Add(2); // упаковка №2
int n1 = (int)numbers[0]; // распаковка №1
int n2 = (int)numbers[1]; // распаковка №2
```

Ну и как вы сами упомянули, такое использование не является типобезопасным.

Обобщенные коллекции и были введены в .NET 2.0 как раз для того, чтобы избежать этих проблем. В более ранних версиях использовался `ArrayList`, который, по большому счету, является аналогом `List<object>`.

**UPD**

В приведенном вами примере все то же самое: в случае, если в массив `storage` будут добавляться экземпляры значимых типов, будет происходить упаковка.

Comment: Я не совсем понял про упаковку и распаковку. А если говорить не о коллекциях, а о массиве целых чисел `int[] items`, то будет ли существовать разница между приведением `object[] items` к `int[] items` и через параметризацию `T[] items`? Если можете, расскажите подробнее про процесс конкретизации типа в том и другом случае.

Comment: Разница в том, что в случае `object[]` вам нужно приводить к `int[]`, а в случае `T[]` -- приведение вообще не нужно. Потому что при использовании `SomeClass<int>` компилятор сгенерирует класс, в котором будет поле `private int[] storage`. И так для каждого типа-параметра.

Comment: Т.е. этот вопрос для `SomeClass<int>` решается на этапе компиляции?

Comment: Да. Обязательно почитайте [что-нибудь](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level11/11_1.php) о том, как работают обобщения. Судя по всему, вы только знакомитесь с C# и .NET, поэтому настоятельно рекомендую прочитать книгу Рихтера "CLR via C#". Более полный список литературы [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/).

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: На здоровье! :)

Answer (score 7):

**Преимущества** обобщенного кода, над не обобщенным:

- **Безопасность типов.** Когда обобщенный алгоритм применяется с    конкретным типом, компилятор и CLR понимают это и следят за тем, чтобы в алгоритме использовались лишь объекты, совместимые с этим типом данных. Попытка использования несовместимого объекта приведет к ошибке на этапе компиляции или исключению во время выполнения.

  Объявив `SomeType<Stream> some = new SomeType<Stream>()` в вашей переменной `storage` можно будет хранить только объекты типа `Stream` или производные от него. Проверка будет происходить на этапе написания кода, т.е. сразу же выдаст предупреждение, в отличие от `object` - на этапе выполнения.
- **Более простой и понятный код.** Поскольку компилятор обеспечивает
  безопасность типов, в исходном тексте требуется меньше операция
  приведения типов, а такой код проще писать и сопровождать.
- **Повышение производительности.** До появления обобщений один из способов
  определения обобщенного алгоритма заключался в таком определении всех
  его членов, чтобы они «умели» работать с типом данных Object. Чтобы
  алгоритм работал с экземплярами значимого типа, перед вызовом членов
  алгоритма среда CLR должна была упаковать этот экземпляр. Упаковка требует выделения памяти в управляемой
  куче, что приводит к более частым процедурам уборки мусора, а это, в
  свою очередь, снижает производительность приложения. Поскольку
  обобщенный алгоритм можно создать для работы с конкретным значимым
  типом, экземпляры значимого типа могут передаваться по значению и CLR
  не нужно выполнять упаковку. Операции приведения типа также не нужны, поэтому CLR не нужно контролировать
  безопасность типов при их преобразовании, что также ускоряет работу
  кода.

---

Для оценки производительности был использован не обобщенный `ArrayList` из библиотеки классов **FCL** и обобщенный `List`.

Метод `Main` - вызов двух тестов

```
public static void Main() {    
   ValueTypePerfTest();    
   ReferenceTypePerfTest();  
}
```

**Тестирование значимых типов:**

```
 private static void ValueTypePerfTest() {    
    const Int32 count = 10000000;

    using (new OperationTimer("List<Int32>")) {      
        List<Int32> l = new List<Int32>();      
        for (Int32 n = 0; n < count; n++) {         
            l.Add(n);                 // Без упаковки         
            Int32 x = l[n];           // Без распаковки      
        }       
        l = null; // Для удаления в процессе уборки мусора   
    }

    using (new OperationTimer("ArrayList of Int32")) {      
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();      
        for (Int32 n = 0; n < count; n++) {         
            a.Add(n);                  // Упаковка         
            Int32 x = (Int32) a[n];    // Распаковка      
        }       
        a = null; // Для удаления в процессе уборки мусора   
    } 
}
```

**Тестирование ссылочных типов:**

```
private static void ReferenceTypePerfTest() {  
    const Int32 count = 10000000;

    using (new OperationTimer("List<String>")) {    
        List<String> l = new List<String>();    
        for (Int32 n = 0; n < count; n++) {       
            l.Add("X");                   // Копирование ссылки       
            String x = l[n];              // Копирование ссылки    
        }     
        l = null; // Для удаления в процессе уборки мусора  
    }

    using (new OperationTimer("ArrayList of String")) {      
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();      
        for (Int32 n = 0; n < count; n++) {         
            a.Add("X");                 // Копирование ссылки         
            String x = (String) a[n];   // Проверка преобразования       
        }                             // и копирование ссылки       
        a = null; // Для удаления в процессе уборки мусора
    }
}
```

**Класс для оценки времени выполнения операций**

```
internal sealed class OperationTimer : IDisposable {  
    private Int64 m_startTime;  
    private String m_text;  
    private Int32 m_collectionCount;

    public OperationTimer(String text) {    
        PrepareForOperation();
        m_text = text;    
        m_collectionCount = GC.CollectionCount(0);
        // Эта команда должна быть последней в этом методе     
        // для максимально точной оценки быстродействия    
        m_startTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();  
    }

    public void Dispose() {     
        Console.WriteLine("{0} (GCs={1,3}) {2}", (m_stopwatch.Elapsed),        
            GC.CollectionCount(0), m_collectionCount, m_text);  
    }

    private static void PrepareForOperation() {    
        GC.Collect();    
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();    
        GC.Collect();  
    } 
}
```

---

**Результаты  тестирования**

> ```
> 00:00:01.6246959 (GCs=  6) List<Int32> 
> 00:00:10.8555008 (GCs=390) ArrayList of Int32 
> 00:00:02.5427847 (GCs=  4) List<String> 
> 00:00:02.7944831 (GCs=  7) ArrayList of String
> ```

---

**Вывод**

С типом Int32 обобщенный алгоритм List работает гораздо быстрее, чем не обобщенный алгоритм ArrayList. Более того, **разница** огромная: 1,6 секунды против 11 секунд, то есть **в 7 раз быстрее**! Кроме того, использование значимого типа (Int32) с алгоритмом ArrayList требует множества операций упаковки, и, как результат, **390 процедур уборки мусора**, а в алгоритме List их всего 6.

**Результаты тестирования для ссылочного** типа не столь впечатляющие: временные показатели и число операций уборки мусора здесь **примерно одинаковы**. Поэтому в данном случае у обобщенного алгоритма List реальных преимуществ нет. Тем не менее помните, что применение обобщенного алгоритма **значительно упрощает код и контроль типов при компиляции**.

---

**Источник:** Jeffrey Richter "CLR via C#"

Comment: По первому пункту непонятно. Можно ж пользоваться `ArrayList`'ом и без исходников?

Comment: @VladD Вы не правильно меня поняли. Это идет сравнение с C++ и здесь упоминается о доступе к коду класса, а не к сборке

Comment: Я понял, да, но вопрос вроде бы этого не упоминал? В вопросе говорится о разнице между `T[] storage` и `object[] storage` _в рамках C#_, разве нет?

Comment: @VladD поправил. Текущий ответ не выходит за рамки C#

Comment: Ага, спасибо! (Мой +1 уже стоит.)